# JS, HTML,CSS and Python(Django)

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I have a form in the html. And obviously an input box with a unique id.

THe uerenters clicks on the search input box and types the query.

Clicks on a button that is linked with javascript to provide js with whatever was entered in the input box.

But I have a python.py file which is where I want to use the term entered by the user.

How do I make the JS interact with Python? Web servers? Sockets? Whatever. Tell me steps.

Now, I have seen answers on SO and links that redirct to google app engine and so.

But If someone could provide me the step wise instructions as to how to get this done, maybe?

Comment: To send data via javascript to server(python).you can do simple http request.using jquery or ajax...i think you are missing this...serach for exaples for how to send data to python via javascript in django

Comment: -1 Seems too broad a question for SO. Do some research, complete a few tutorials and when you run into some specific  problem, SO will be better able to help you.

Comment: Did you even read the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use web frameworks like Django, web2py. If you do not need a full stack framework, I recommend to you [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/).